# Android NavigationDrawer lagging while opening and closing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, lag

I have activity with NavigationDrawer. When I click on icon in ActionBar, NavigationBar opens, but with lags. Identical is with closing. I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6f6sbtgd6v0 How to remove lags?

```
    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lvMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
    drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    return drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerListener.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    lvMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it in a physical device? It usually lags in emulator

Comment: Yes, i use physical device, which has 1GB RAM and 4x 1,20 GHz.

Comment: try this tested and works without any problem.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I found reason of problem. It is ImageView in Fragment. If I delete ImageView, NavigationDrawer works perfectly, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried load image in AsyncTask, but this not help ;/.

Answer (score 3):

My team and I faced the same issue of lagging navigation drawer. On half of the screens performance was good but on the other half it lagged all the time. It turned out that that in some cases `ViewRoorImpl.performTraversals()` was calling `performLayout()` that gave the performance penalty.

To fix this we assigned **constant** values to navigation drawer's `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes ie.

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You may also want to enable hardware acceleration on activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SomeActivity"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do your transaction operation after the drawer closed

then enable hardware acceleration on activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
private void DrawerLayout_DrawerClosed(object sender, DrawerLayout.DrawerClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (fragment != null)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, fragment);
        ft.Commit();
    }
}

public async  void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.HideSoftKeyboard();
        x= e.MenuItem.ItemId;
        switch (x)
        {
            case (Resource.Id.nav1):
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                title = "Fragment1";
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav2):
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                title = "Fragment2";
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav3):
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                title = "Fragment3";
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav4):
                fragment = new Fragment4();
                title = "Fragment4";
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_settings):
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SettingsActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_About):
                Intent intentabout = new Intent(this, typeof(AboutActivity));
                StartActivity(intentabout);
                break;
        }
        if (SupportActionBar != null)
        {
            SupportActionBar.Title = title;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
    }
}
```